# How to get selected value from dropdown item in blazor

Tags: blazor

I have write a below code to show dropdown menu using bootstrap class.I would like to know how to get selected value from dropdown item using blazor.

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:flex-end">
    <div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu2" type="button">
                <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"/>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary dropdown-menu-right">
                <a class="dropdown-item">
                    <i class="fab fa-apple-pay"/>English</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item">
                    <i class="fas fa-bell-slash"/>Tamil</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, format the code better.

Comment: Sure, but first, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The Dropdown as you've shown it is not a "Select" type control.  It's just a list of links that navigate somewhere when one is selected.  You need to use a select input control if you actually want to select and item and then read what you've selected.